# Downloading videos off website in Java/Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, download, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

As a bit of a side project, I wanted to create a program friendly for students at my university to download lectures that are posted online.

The videos are available online, and to watch them, users would first login to their university account, navigate to the list of courses that have online lectures, click the course and watch the lecture. To download them, users would need to install a 3rd party extension (like Video Downloader Professional) and download the lectures

I wanted to create a small applet where students input their

1. Login user and password for the university website
2. The course they wish to download
3. The lecture number of this course/option for all lectures to download
4. The download path for where to save these lectures

Program would then create a new browser window, login to the website, go to that course, and download the lecture number they want.

I ideally want to run this in the background where users can't see what is going on. I know PhantonJS can run invisible, but is there a way for Chrome to do this?

**So my Question:
Is Selenium a good idea for this?**

**How do I make a Google Chrome instance invisible for the end user in Selenium?**

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver

Comment: Selenium don't support applet.

Comment: @MacGyver I have already seen that link :) , I will be using a 3rd party extension to do the downloading on startup of a Chrome instance with Selenium, but concern is actually making Chrome driver invisible

Comment: Is `start-minimized` good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to run [Chrome Headless](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747). This is not an obvious task (although it might be in the [near future](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=label:Proj-Headless)) and requires prerequisites.

So the answer is no, Selenium isn't a good idea for it. It can do it but you have better options for downloading a file in a background process... any programming or scripting language can do it (including the authentication part) and much easier than [downloading files with WebDriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Could you point me in the right direction for how to utilize something like Python/Java to navigate to a webpage in the background and download something (without using Selenium) ? The main issue is honestly logging onto the university website, I know I can do it in Selenium but I'm having a hard time visualizing how to do it in other ways

Comment: Glad to help. I need more information, what OS your using and is Java or python already installed? And do you have coding or scripting skills? BTW, there's a way in SO to say that the answer helped you ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into a headless Selenium chrome instance, but I found for my purpose a chrome instance with it in a position that's outside the view. However, that's a really unprofessional workaround. OS: Windows 10. Yeah I have Python and Java installed, and am comfortable in both, some knowledge of JS. However, other than using Selenium, I have no idea how I can navigate to my universitiy's login page, entering the credentials. Getting the video after that is the easy part. I would vote your answer the best, but my question isn't resolved yet :)